# How to deal with a short in a cat 5e cable

Tags: networking, wiring, cat5e

I am in the process of cleaning up my cables and as part of it testing all connections.  One cat5e wire that snakes thru the walls and I can NOT replace as it's not going to pull around the bends, is showing what seems like a short according to my simple tester.  It goes thru wire 1, 2, 3, 4, and then 5 and 6 light up, then when it would be showing 6 5 and 6 flicker and stay lit again, then goes to 7 and 8.  This happens with the connectors on either end not plugged into anything.  As a matter of fact if I connect the battery powered end of the tester on one end, and don't connect the other end it still does this.  I replaced one side of the connector but not the other.  Any recommendation on what to do?  I have heard there are devices that can literally tell you how far along the cable the short is, but not sure if I would have access to one at the local home depot or what.  Thoughts on how to troubleshoot this?  Or a different way to wire up the connection to get the most use out of the cable as is?

Thanks.

JR

Answer (score 4):

Replace the cable or retire it.